# Prove or disprove asymptotic relation of two sets

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I am looking for a while to prove or disprove: (preparing for finals)
O(f(n)-g(n)) ⊂ |O(f(n)) - O(g(n))|
where || is absolute value. Note that ⊂ is needed and not ⊆

I assumed the a subtraction operator between 2 O() means:
`t1(n) is O(f(n)) and t2(n) is O(g(n))` and so `t1(n)-t2(n)≤O(f(n)) - O(g(n))`
I also noted that `f(n)≥g(n)` otherwise the left side of the proof is invalid.
I am n ot sure how to proceed.
I started at the left side with:

```
t(n) is O(f(n)-g(n))

t(n)≤c*(f(n)-g(n)) (c>0,n≥n0)

t(n)≤c*f(n)-c*g(n)
```

I dont know how to proceed from here and how to prove that the right side has a member that doesnt belong to the left side (proper subset rule)
Thank you for any assistance.